# MySql performance is really slow

Tags: mysql

```
$remainingQuery = "select * from $value s
where not exists (
    select userID from userLocations ul 
    where ul.userID = s.userID
    )  AND (userIP > '') GROUP BY userIP LIMIT 1"; 
$remainingResults = mysql_query($remainingQuery) or die(mysql_error());
```

The above code performs really slow. Anybody who knows why?

Here is info about the table userLocations.

```
enum('ipv4', 'ipv6')    latin1_swedish_ci
ip_start    varbinary(16)
ip_end  varbinary(16)
country char(2)
stateprov   varchar(80)
city    varchar(80)
```

Here is one of the tables which are named in $value

```
name    varchar(20)
score   bigint(20)
log longtext
difficulty  int(10)
games   int(11)
checkSum    text
bought  tinyint(1)
time    timestamp
bundle  int(11)
userID  text
userIP  text
city    text
country text
```

Comment: I added more info, do you need anything more?

Comment: How slow is *really slow* ?

Comment: 10 seconds or so, normally, loading the page and getting it presented only takes 0.5seconds, mostly due to my own slow connection to my server.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things with your query. First, you are grouping by userIP and limiting by 1. This will return only one userIP, is that what you really want? How do you know which userIP is being returned?

Perhaps using `NOT IN` will be faster than what you have?

```
SELECT *
FROM table s
WHERE s.userID NOT IN (SELECT userId FROM userLocations) AND (userIP > '')
GROUP BY userIP
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: still really slow. I don't know what is causing it

Comment: I figured, I just thought I'd take a shot. I'll probably remove this answer, as maybe there is something else going on.